# exporting consts from CommonJS app amd require them in another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

I want to export `const config` from `config.js` file in CommonJs app.

```
const config = {
    development: {
        client: 'pg',
        connection: {
            database: 'myDatabase',
            user: 'myUser',
            host: 'localhost',
            password: 'password',
            port: PORT,
            ssl: {
                rejectUnauthorized: false
            }
        },
        server: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: 'PORT2'
        }
    }

module.exports = config;
```

and in `index.js` I require that like

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require('./config')[env];

const knexDB = knex({
    client: config.client, 
    connection: {
        database: config.database,
        user: config.user,
        host: config.host,
        password: config.password,
        port: config.port,
        ssl: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    }
});
```

But in the config file. IntelliSense recommends changing `module.exports` to ES `export` which I don't want to do and keep the app CommonJS. also, config object in index.js I have this error :

```
Property 'host' does not exist on type '{ development: { client: string; connection: { database: string; user: string; host: string; password: string; port: number; ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: boolean; }; }; server: { host: string; port: string; }; }; production: { ...; }; }'.ts(2339)
```

How can I export config from config.js?

Comment: That error applies to all properties of config, I just paste one of them. I tried `config.development` and `config.development.client` but not working.

Comment: Do the same for the rest. all of them are not implemented properly. you missed the `connection` property on `host `and `user` too.

Comment: I added these `const dotenv = require('dotenv'); dotenv.config();` to `config.js` and `index.js`. also tried `config.development.connection.password,` this approch, still undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the **wrong property of config**. It must be `config.development.host` . give up on the vscode requesting a CommonJS module.leave it alone. You also have 2 options more to configure your constant data.

1. `yarn add dotenv`
2. `npm install config`

Answer (score 0):

Check config file you Db details is inside config.development.connection but you are reading it from config.

```
const knexDB = knex({
    client: config.development.client, 
    connection: {
        database: config.development.connection.database,
        user: config.development.connection.user,
        host: config.development.connection.host,
        password: config.development.connection.password,
        port: config.development.connection.port,
        ssl: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    }
```

But instead of this use config or env

Answer (score 0):

well, I found a way to work around it. I removed `connection` from `development` and it worked! just mention I used `config.connection.client` and `config.development.connection.client` or other variables in the connection but still not working in the `index.js`.
so it looks like

```
const config = {
    development: {
        client: 'pg',
        database: 'myDatabase',
        user: 'myUser',
        host: 'localhost',
        password: 'password',
        port: PORT,
        ssl: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
        server: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: 'PORT2'
        }
    }

module.exports = config;
```

and in `index.js` I access that like

```
const configure = require('./config.js')[env];
const knexDB = knex({
    client: configure.client, 
    connection: {
        database: configure.database, 
        user: configure.user,
        host: configure.host,
        password: configure.password,
        port: configure.port,
        ssl: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    }
});
```

thanks for everyone for thier contribution.